# 「サーバ通信」タグの使用は適切でしょうか？

Tags: 討議, タグ

[サーバ通信](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%90%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1) というタグがありますが、今のところタグwikiの説明は特に記載されていません。

このタグが割り当てられたいくつかの質問を見る限り、恐らく「サーバとの通信がうまくいかない」という文脈で作られたのかもしれませんが、一般的には「サーバとクライアント」のペアがあっての話なので、"サーバ通信" という言い回しは(個人的に)馴染みがありません。

質問を分類するなら、より具体的な「何のサーバ、プロトコルなのか」等で絞り込むべきで、この
"サーバ通信" というタグは不適当なように思いますが如何でしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

タグを消してしまって良いと思います。理由は以下の通りです。

- 意味が曖昧であるため。サーバー・クライアントモデルにおけるサーバーとクライアント間の通信のことなのか、ネットワーク構造で「サーバー」と呼ばれているデバイス同士が通信していることなのかよく分からない。
- 他のタグで充分そうであるため。現在 [サーバ通信](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%90%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1) がついている質問は、他についてあるタグだけで充分であったり、[network](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network) 等で代用できそうです。必要であれば [クライアントサーバモデル](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%af%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%82%a2%e3%83%b3%e3%83%88%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%90%e3%83%a2%e3%83%87%e3%83%ab) タグを新設しても良いでしょう。
- 英語版 Stack Overflow に [サーバ通信](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%90%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1) と対応しそうなタグ [[server-communication]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-communication) が一応あったのですが、現在 44 個しか質問が投稿されていないため。このタグの説明には「サーバーへ、またはサーバーからデータを送信する方法」と書かれているのですが、いまいちタグとしての役割を果たしているように思えません。

---

2020年2月20日追記：[サーバ通信](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%90%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1) のタグがついていた質問全 10 個から、タグを削除して必要に応じてタグを付け替える作業を行いました。