# 「サーバ通信」とはどういうタグですか？

Tags: サポート, タグ

[サーバ通信](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b5%e3%83%bc%e3%83%90%e9%80%9a%e4%bf%a1) というタグを見つけましたが、タグ wiki がなく、どういう質問につけるタグなのかいまいち分かりませんでした。

これはどういう意味のタグでしょうか？

Comment: 重複候補: [「サーバ通信」タグの使用は適切でしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3102)

Comment: 確かに！　見てみたら自分でも回答していてびっくりです。重複でクローズします。